# HttpListener - seamless start/stop on same address without downtime?

Tags: c#, httplistener

I'm trying to seamlessly switch between two independent HttpListener instances on the same address. Currently, there are a few seconds of downtime (where the user would get a 404) after stopping instance 1 and starting instance 2 (and obviously, if instance 2 is started before instance 1 has closed, I get the classic "already registered with http.sys" error).

Any ideas on how to seamlessly switch (without downtime) on the same address?

Comment: Please give me context - are these on the same machine, the same process, behind a load balancer etc... what's your situation?

Comment: same machine, same process but different AppDomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic answer here is an external load-balancer, such as HAProxy, that spreads the load between multiple machines, processes, ports, hosts, whatever. For example, even on a single machine you could have two instances on different ports (unrelated to what the client thinks they are contacting), and switch load to them via HAProxy. This handles all the port / host remapping automatically.

If you want a single process (such as a service), then a trick here is to use AppDomain:

- the service we is a shell that just deals with http, but process requests via...
- ... a MarshalByRefObject which is a proxy to a real object in a child AppDomain ...
- ... which you can create on the fly whenever you need to upgrade, simply swapping the proxy instance when the new domain is ready...
- ... and then unload the obsolete AppDomain

A little messy (you need to worry about creating temporary locations for each version of the app to execute from, etc), but can be very effective.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'm actually currently using AppDomains - hence the 2 instances. The issue is the downtime between unloading/loading. I'll check out HAProxy in the meantime!

Comment: @trebuchet ah, you see the subtle distinction I made? In my version, the http work is all done by the shell process. So never gets shut down, even momentarily. HttpListener stays only in the shell exe, but doesn't do any application logic.

Comment: @trebuchet but indeed, using multiple ports and HAProxy would work well too. Extra cogs, but very well-proven cogs.

Comment: @trebuchet something else to consider: the Internet *generally* has small stutters, and any client application should expect very brief stalls. Would it really be noticeable if you were down for half a second while swapping?

Comment: marc, not the end of the world by any means, but if it could be avoided within reason that would be ideal